# Visualforce pop-up with apex code

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

My page is currently using a text box to update the `BillingCountry` field of an Account. How can I create a pop-up window with the same update functionality?

## Controller

```
public class AccountEditController {

    accountwrapper1 makeEdit;
    List<accountwrapper1> listAccount = new List<accountwrapper1>();
    List<Account> selectableAccount = new List<Account>();
    List<Account> selectableAccount2 = new List<Account>();
    public Boolean showPopup { get; set; }

   public AccountEditController() {
          showPopup = False;
   }

    public List<accountwrapper1> getAccounts() {
            for(Account a: [SELECT Id, Name, BillingCountry, Phone FROM Account])
            listAccount.add(new accountwrapper1(a));
            return listAccount;            
    }

     public PageReference showToPopup() {
        showPopUp = True;
         selectableAccount.clear();
        for(accountwrapper1 accwrapper : listAccount)
        if(accwrapper.selected == True)
        selectableAccount.add(accwrapper.acc);
        system.debug(selectableAccount);
        return Null;
    }

    public string BillingCountry {
        get; 
        set;
    }


    public PageReference Savemeth() {
        for(account acc :selectableAccount ) {
                acc.BillingCountry = BillingCountry;
                  selectableAccount2.add(acc);
        }    
    update selectableAccount2;
    return Null;

    }

    public PageReference cancelmeth() {        
        return Null;
    }

    public PageReference closePopup() {
        showPopup = False;    
        return Null;
    }

    public PageReference GetSelectedAccounts()
    {
       if(selectableAccount.size()>0) {
        system.debug(selectableAccount.size());
        system.debug(selectableAccount);
       return Null;
        }
        else
        return Null;
    } 


     public class accountwrapper1
    {             
        public Account acc{get; set;}      
        public Boolean selected {get; set;}
        public accountwrapper1(Account a)
        {
            acc = a;
            selected = False;
        }
    }
}
```

## Page

```
<apex:page controller="AccountEditController" applyHtmlTag="true">
    <style type="text/css">
    .PopupBackground{
        background-color:black;
        opacity: 0.20;
        filter: alpha(opacity = 20);
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 9998;
    }
    .AccountEdit{
        background-color: white;
        border-width: 2px;
        border-style: solid;
        z-index: 9999;
        left: 50%;
        padding:10px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 500px;
        margin-left: -250px;
        top:100px;
    }
    </style>
        <apex:form >
            <apex:pageBlock Title="List of Accounts" >

                   <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                        <apex:commandButton value="Get selected Records" action="{!showToPopUp}" rerender="Output" id="button"/>
                   </apex:pageBlockButtons>

                 <!-- {!showPanel}---->
                      <apex:outputPanel id="Output" >
                           <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!showPopUp}">
                           <!---{!showPanel}---------->
                               <apex:outputLabel value="BillingCountry: "></apex:outputLabel>
                               <apex:inputText id="BillingCountry" value="{!BillingCountry}" size="40" style="height:13px;font-size:11px;"/>                   
                               <apex:commandButton value="save" action="{!Savemeth}"/>
                               <apex:commandButton value="cancel" action="{!cancelmeth}"/>
                               <apex:commandButton value="cancelPopUp" action="{!closePopUp}"/>
                            </apex:outputPanel>                   
                        </apex:outputPanel>  
                 <!--   <apex:commandButton value="cancelPopUp" action="{!closePopUp}"/>--->
                   <apex:pageBlockSection Title="List of Available Accounts" columns="1" collapsible="false">
                            <apex:pageblockTable value="{!accounts}" var="a" >

                                <apex:column headerValue="Select" width="60">
                                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!a.Selected}" id="checkedone" />
                                </apex:column>

                                <apex:column headervalue="Account Name" value="{!a.acc.Name}" width="200"/>
                                <apex:column headervalue="Phone" value="{!a.acc.Phone}" width="300"/>
                                <apex:column headervalue="Billing Country" value="{!a.acc.BillingCountry}" width="300"/>

                            </apex:pageblocktable>
                   </apex:pageBlockSection>

            </apex:pageblock>
        </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: so , what exactly is the issue here? what is not working and where?  Perhaps a screen shot of what UI behavior you are getting would be useful

Comment: @cropredy Here the model popup is not working it's working like a ordinary button action when clicking the "Get selected Records" the textbox and the save and another  2 buttons are showed (But it's not in show by model popup)it's my problem.I want the text box and the buttons showed by the inside the modelpopup.

Comment: Please use [edit] and post an annotated screen shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Friends I got the answer of my question:
The Controller:

```
public class AccountEditController {

    public String closePopup { get; set; }

    accountwrapper1 makeEdit;
    List<accountwrapper1> listAccount = new List<accountwrapper1>();
    List<Account> selectableAccount = new List<Account>();
    //set<Account> selectableAccount2 = new set<Account>();
    //public Boolean showPanel {get; set;}
    public Boolean showPopup { get; set; }

   public AccountEditController() {
          showPopup = False;
         //showPanel = False;
   }

    public List<accountwrapper1> getAccounts() {
        if(listAccount == Null){
            for(Account a: [SELECT Id, Name, BillingCountry, Phone FROM Account])
            listAccount.add(new accountwrapper1(a));
            return listAccount; }
        else{
            listAccount.clear();
            for(Account a: [SELECT Id, Name, BillingCountry, Phone FROM Account])
            listAccount.add(new accountwrapper1(a));
            return listAccount;            
            }           
    }

     public PageReference showToPopup() {
   // public PageReference showToPanel() {
        showPopUp = True;
        //showPanel  = True;
         selectableAccount.clear();
        for(accountwrapper1 accwrapper : listAccount)
        if(accwrapper.selected == True)
        selectableAccount.add(accwrapper.acc);
        system.debug(selectableAccount);
        return Null;              
    }

    public string BillingCountry {
        get; 
        set;
    }


    /*public PageReference Savemeth() {
        for(account acc :selectableAccount ) {
                acc.BillingCountry = BillingCountry;
                selectableAccount2.add(acc);

        }    
    update selectableAccount2;
    showPopup = False;
    return Null;

    }*/

    public PageReference Savemeth() 
    {
        map<Id, Account> mapAccountForUpdate = new map<Id, Account>();
        for(account acc :selectableAccount ) 
        {
            acc.BillingCountry = BillingCountry;
            mapAccountForUpdate.put(acc.Id, acc);
        }    
        update mapAccountForUpdate.values();
        showPopup = Null;
        BillingCountry = '';
        //showPopup = False;
        return Null;
    }

    public PageReference cancelmeth() {        
        return Null;
    }

    public PageReference closePopup() {
        showPopup = Null;
        BillingCountry = '';
        //showPopup = False;   
        return Null;
    }

    public PageReference GetSelectedAccounts()
    {
       if(selectableAccount.size()>0) {
        system.debug(selectableAccount.size());
        system.debug(selectableAccount);
        showPopup = Null;
        return Null;
        }
        else
        showPopup = Null;
        return Null;
    } 


     public class accountwrapper1
    {             
        public Account acc{get; set;}      
        public Boolean selected {get; set;}
        public accountwrapper1(Account a)
        {
            acc = a;
            selected = False;
        }
    }
}
```

My Page:

```
<apex:page controller="AccountEditController" applyHtmlTag="true">
    <style type="text/css">
    .PopupBackground{
        background-color: white;
        opacity: 0.8;
        filter: alpha(opacity = 20);
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 200%;
        top: -100px;
        left: 10px;
        z-index: 9998;
    }
    .AccountEdit{
        background-color: white;
        border-width: 8px;
        border-style: solid;
        z-index: 9999;
        left: 30%;
        padding:10px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 350px;
        margin-left: 75px;
        top:300px;
    }
    </style>
        <apex:form >
            <apex:pageBlock Title="List of Accounts" >

                   <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
                        <apex:commandButton value="Get selected Records" action="{!showToPopup}" rerender="Output" id="button"/>
                        <apex:commandButton value="cancelPopup" action="{!closePopup}" rendered="output"/>
                      <!-- <apex:commandButton value="Get selected Records" action="{!showToPanel}" rerender="Output" id="button"/>---->

                   </apex:pageBlockButtons>

                 <!-- {!showPanel}---->
                      <apex:outputPanel id="Output">
                          <apex:outputPanel styleClass="PopupBackground" layout="black" rendered="{!showPopup}">
                              <apex:outputPanel styleClass="AccountEdit" layout="black" rendered="{!showPopup}">
                         <!---  <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!showPanel}">----->
                           <!---{!showPanel}---------->
                               <apex:outputLabel value="BillingCountry: "></apex:outputLabel>
                               <apex:inputText id="BillingCountry" value="{!BillingCountry}" size="40" style="height:13px;font-size:11px;"/><br />                   
                               <center><apex:commandButton value="save" action="{!Savemeth}" reRender="Initialtable,Output"/>
                              <!-- <apex:commandButton value="cancel" action="{!cancelmeth}"/>---->
                               <apex:commandButton value="cancelPopup" action="{!closePopup}"/></center>
                                </apex:outputPanel>
                            </apex:outputPanel>                   
                        </apex:outputPanel>  
                 <!--   <apex:commandButton value="cancelPopup" action="{!closePopup}"/>--->
                   <apex:pageBlockSection Title="List of Available Accounts" columns="1" collapsible="true">
                            <apex:pageblockTable value="{!accounts}" var="a" id="Initialtable">

                                <apex:column headerValue="Select" width="60">
                                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!a.Selected}" id="checkedone" />
                                </apex:column>

                                <apex:column headervalue="Account Name" value="{!a.acc.Name}" width="200"/>
                                <apex:column headervalue="Phone" value="{!a.acc.Phone}" width="300"/>
                                <apex:column headervalue="Billing Country" value="{!a.acc.BillingCountry}" width="300"/>

                            </apex:pageblocktable>
                   </apex:pageBlockSection>

            </apex:pageblock>
        </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Thank you By Mohan.